# what are the new features of gnome 3.6?

Tags: gnome

What are the new features included in GNOME 3.6?

Can somebody brief the features that are worth trying out in new GNOME.

It will be great if you add the steps to install it.

Thanks

Comment: Just an additional info for users who might want to try Gnome 3.6. Gnome 3.6 is just released and is stable. But not all extensions are compatible with new version. So if you use extensions(http://extensions.gnome.org/) more , better to wait for some time , atleast till Ubuntu 12.10 is released :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site mentions that the new release includes

> - Big improvements to notifications, including a redesigned Message Tray, smarter notifications, and other tweaks and refinements.
> - An enhanced Activities Overview with an improved layout.
> - A greatly enhanced Files application, with functional file search, a new Recent location, redesigned interface and lots of bug fixes and
>     handy new features.
> - Integrated Input Sources, which makes inputting different character sets (eg. Japanese or Chinese) fast and easy.
> - Accessibility on demand, meaning that universal access features like the Orca screen reader can be enabled with the push of a button.
> - A new Lock Screen. This provides an attractive view when the device is locked, plus handy functionality like media controls and
>     notifications.

Here is the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMfg7Jsnmg4) from webupd8, which covers the new features of GNOME 3.6

To install GNOME 3.6 you can download the ISO from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/misc/promo-usb/GNOME-3.6.0.iso)

Answer (score 1):

It delivers a number of major new features, including:

1. A reworked Activities Overview, updated message tray and notifications.
2. An enhanced Files application.
3. Improved accessibility support and integrated input sources for using different 
   languages.
4. Incorporates a host of smaller enhancements.
5. May send numerologists to their calendars, but we're not that way inclined
6. Adds a new Boxes application
7. usual raft of tweaks and bug fixes you'd expect from an update like this.

Together, these changes make GNOME 3 better than ever before.

Refer to this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/gnome-36-released-see-whats-new.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the key features of the GNOME 3.6 update are:

> #### Activities Overview
>
> New applications button and improved layout.
>
> #### Lock Screen
>
> A useful and attractive screen when the screen is locked, plus a new
> login experience.
>
> #### Message Tray
>
> Major updates make it better looking and easier to use.
>
> #### Notifications
>
> Smarter, more noticeable, easier to dismiss.
>
> #### System Settings
>
> Better looking main interface, many settings have also been improved
> and extended.
>
> #### User Menu
>
> Streamlined user menu with a Power Off by default.

The official changelog can be found [here](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/).

You should be able to install GNOME with `sudo apt-get install gnome`.

Don't forget that you will have to select GNOME as your window manager on your login screen.